# Fragment in front of activity

Tags: android, fragment

I'm new in Android and I'm trying to understand the fragment view.
I have this stupid activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.ale.myapplication10.FragmentActivity">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Yeah"
    android:onClick="prova"
    android:id="@+id/button" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="adadad"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="38dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="38dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="67dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And I want a Fragment that overlays the second button. How can i do?

Comment: Wow, I bet it hurts the feelings of that stupid activity! But it always comes back to you; you wrote it!

Comment: @Kurlicue that overlaying the button

Comment: You can create it in xml, and put the visibility to gone, and then in java you can put the visibility to VISIBILE when you want to show it